# Making code stuff pretty (layout)

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

So I have made a little piece of code that will insert and manipulate a few images. Now my main problem is that this is very ugly and long, I was wondering if anything could be done to make it prettier.

```
    RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.board);

    ImageView i = new ImageView(this);
    i.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue_1);
    i.setId(400);

    ImageView j = new ImageView(this);
    j.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_1);
    j.setId(401);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(40,62);
    params.addRule(mRelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(40,62);
    params1.addRule(mRelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    params1.addRule(mRelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, 400);    

    mRelativeLayout.addView(i, params);
    mRelativeLayout.addView(j, params1);
    setContentView(mRelativeLayout);
```

For example I have tried with just one layoutparams, but it seem to affect both pictures even if I make changes to it after the first picture is added.

Also I have a function that can return a string such as blue_1 o red_1 as a string to help me print my images, but it wont allow me to put strings into the i.setImageResource to get the picture :(

What can i do?

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to do this in code rather than in a layout xml file? Is there a reason you're trying to compose strings to refer to resources rather than using the resource ID values themselves?

Comment: yeah, i want it dynamically, trying to make a card game :) so it would be easier for me to draw the cards on the hand forexample with just a hand.getCard(); into the setImageResource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to tidy your code up would be to get rid of almost all of it and just define your layout in an XML file. That way you can just call `setContentView(R.layout.my_layout_name)` instead of manually creating the widgets and layout params yourself. If you're not too familiar with declaring layouts in XML, have a look at [the dev docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html). Alternatively, if you need to instantiate different parts of the UI separately, you can *inflate* the layout with a [`LayoutInflater`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html).

For the second question, the `Resources` class has a `getIdentifier` method. You can do something like this:

```
getResources().getIdentifier("blue_1", "drawable", "com.my.package.here")
```

That'll return the resource ID, which you can then use instead of `R.drawable.blue_1`.

Comment: ah awesome with the last part was what I was looking for :) Ill look into the inflater as well :)

Comment: also this helped me out a bit :) getResources().getIdentifier("blue_1", "drawable", getPackageName());